# Attempting to mask a circle around an image not working

Tags: ios, uiimageview, mask, cornerradius

I have an image that I am attempting to mask a circle around so the image appears round. This somewhat works but the circle comes to a point on the top and bottom.

```
profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.width/2;
profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Should this code be drawing a perfect circle? It seems to draw a circle in one place but in two other places, its not working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the best results masking the image view with a `CAShapeLayer`:

```
CGFloat radius = self.profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2.0;
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(radius, radius) radius:radius startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI * 2.0 clockwise:TRUE];
CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
layer.path = path.CGPath;
layer.lineWidth = 0;
self.profileImageView.layer.mask = layer;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Should this code be drawing a perfect circle?

Not necessarily. After all, the width and the height of this layer might not be the same. And even if they are, dividing by 2 might not give you a radius that fits perfectly into an integral number of points as they are mapped to pixels on the screen.

It really would be better, if what you want is a mask that's a circle, to give this layer an *actual* mask that is an *actual circle*. Misusing the corner radius as you are doing is just lazy (and, as you've discovered, it's error-prone).

Comment: Thanks Matt I appreciate the info and link.